# How to suppress date when printing elapsed time

Tags: datetime, go, time, gofmt

I have the following Go code used to capture elapsed time:

```
import (
 "time"
)

start := time.Now()
...
end := time.Since(start)
log.Printf("Elapsed Time:  %s", end)
```

The output of which is:

```
2019/10/26 13:22:53 Elapsed Time :  41.867µs
```

I would like the output to be simply:

```
Elapsed Time :  41.867µs
```

Not sure how to supress the time packages default data/clock time output.

Comment: An alternative to Cerise's answer is to use `fmt` instead of `log`.

Comment: Any idea of how I would force the output to always be expressed, purely in the form of millisecond instead of microseconds? Even if the wall time is several minutes in length, I would like the time to be expressed purely in milliseconds.

Comment: How a time.Duration is printed is implemented by the [`String`](https://golang.org/pkg/time/#Duration.String) method, which you cannot change. What you can do however is to use the `%d` verb and divide the duration by `time.Millisecond`. (https://play.golang.com/p/TFJhBeDA8hk)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To log without a date and time, clear the date and time flags:

```
log.SetFlags(log.Flags() &^ (log.Ldate | log.Ltime))
```

Because the default flags are `(log.Ldate | log.Ltime)`, the following also works:

```
log.SetFlags(0)
```